# Can I say blood veins

Tags: single-word-requests

When a person is lack of sleep, his eyes will have some red veins. How to describe this? Can I say "His eyes were full of blood veins?"

Comment: It would be like saying 'water rivers'.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth ~ However, veins may refer to things other than blood vessels. There are veins of gold and other elements or minerals in rocks. And I recall hearing people say: "In that vein" with reference to topics of conversation. But I would say bloodshot eyes, as mentioned in the answer given below.

Comment: Red eyes or bloodshot eyes. Don't make this complicated. You don't know if those are actually veins or arteries or capillaries, plus they are in the eye at all times anyway. There's no point in calling attention to the fact that that person has blood vessels in their body. That sounds weird and even gross. Rather, what you mean to call attention to is that for lack of sleep their eyes have become red or bloodshot. So say just that.

Comment: The red lines in eyes are not referred to as veins. But watch out for pink eyes. [joke, clue: misspelling]

Answer (score 8):

When eyes are red or have veins showing, e.g. from lack of sleep, or from excessive drinking or drug taking, we say that they are 'bloodshot'.

Comment: What about pollen, dust, pet dander, dry air and sun?  I also saw humidity, but I ain't buying that one.

Comment: The big giveaway for me was always marijuana.

Comment: You're giving marijuana away?

Comment: Only at schoolyard gates.

Comment: Just throw in a solid reference and you're done.

Comment: Per the [paywalled OED entry](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/20427): **bloodshot** *adj.* 1. Of the eye: suffused or streaked with blood; *spec.* affected with congestion of the conjunctival blood vessels. 2.  In extended use: that appears as though suffused with blood; streaked with red; intensely red; lurid.